# Как нужно обработать текст что бы его не разбивало на отдельные ячейки при экспорте?

Tags: woocommerce

При экспорте товаров woocomerc в xls файл описание товаров разбивает на несколько разных ячеек. Как нужно обработать текст что бы его не разбивало на отдельные ячейки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в CSV ситуация аналогична

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> Как нужно обработать текст что бы его не разбивало на отдельные ячейки?

Во первых - на скрине я не вижу разбивания описания.
Во вторых экспорт из ВП делается в csv, а уже Экселем или др ПО его можно открывать.

При экспорте настрой разделители, которых нет в описании, а при открытии правильно указывай разделители - настрой свой Эксель.

Comment: в csv ситуация аналогична

Comment: Что значит "аналогична"? Ответ прочти.